# integrated twillio verify service in my App

Tags: twilio

we already created a Twilio service, but don't know how to integrated it into our APP application for user verify ?

where is the demo API ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the Verify service can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api#). As you already created a Verify service instance (**Step 1**), you need to add these two steps in your code:

**Step 2:** Send a Verification Token

```js
client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .verificationChecks
      .create({to: '+15017122661', code: '123456'})
      .then(verification_check => console.log(verification_check.status));
```

**Step 3:** Check the Verification Token

```js
client.verify.v2.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .verificationChecks
      .create({to: '+15017122661', code: '123456'})
      .then(verification_check => console.log(verification_check.status));
```

PS: Other snippets are available on the site I linked above.